# Associate user picture to domain account

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to assign users a picture (o let them assign their own picture) to their user domain account and wherever they log in, that picture should appear as well.

How can I do this using group policy?

All my clients are at least Windows 7 and the server is a Windows Server 2012 R2 with the forest level set to Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: https://www.myotherpcisacloud.com/post/Default-Account-Pictures-via-Active-Directory ?

Comment: This sets a default for everyone. I want to be on my client Windows 7, change the display picture and that applies whereever I log on in the domain for that user.

Comment: With a little creativity you could adapt it to use an environment variable instead so that each user would pull the picture from his or her own profile directory.

Comment: @RyanRies I can do a bunch of things like sync a picture or a path from a data base or scripting. Not really the point. The point is to allow every user to pick their own picture on their own PC and if they logon to another PC, it appears.

Comment: So no way to do this?

Comment: No, I don't think so. What would happen if a user logged on to a new domain-joined laptop while they were disconnected from the network. Where would the profile picture come from?

Comment: The server would push the picture to the client and the client would store a temp copy. Just like GPOs are temp stored.

Comment: What kind of profiles are you using? I'm not sure but I think the profile picture would sync if you were using Roaming Profiles.

Comment: @Arcath Because roaming profiles in a one site AD is pointless.

Comment: @riahc3 they are yes, but they would fix your problem. I think it would be possible with a couple of scripts, one to send the image to a server at logoff and one to apply it on logon. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb776892(v=vs.85).aspx explains where the profile image is saved.

Answer (score 0):

You could theoretically do this easily with the Files section of Group Policy Preferences. In Windows 7, information about user account pictures is stored in `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\User Account Pictures`. Each user has a .DAT binary file that contains the path and information about a picture that has been set.

You could set a user's picture, making sure to store it on a network location so it would be accessible from any system. Then, simply make a copy of the .DAT file, throw it on a network share, and make a GPP Files entry to push it to every computer.

Users wouldn't be able to set their own picture without assistance, but after they did it the first time, it would follow them around.